# Bin average with non-uniform arrays

Tags: python-2.7, binning

I have a set of non-uniform velocity profiles (velocity with altitude) and I need to bin average (bin 1 km) all the profiles. Here's an example of three "synthetic" profiles:

```
testalt1 = np.arange(70,75,1)
testalt2 = np.arange(72,80,1)
testalt3 = np.arange(60,69,1)

vtest1 = np.arange(-2,3,1)
vtest2 = np.arange(-3,5,1)
vtest3 = np.arange(-3,6,1)

print testalt1,testalt2, testalt3
print vtest1,vtest2, vtest3
```

which outputs:

```
[70 71 72 73 74] [72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79] [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68]
[-2 -1  0  1  2] [-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4] [-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5]
```

So the end result of my code should be a profile that averages out whenever there's an overlap and just takes the value of the one array that has it present. For example:

The resulting `altmean` should be:

`[60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]`

From the altitude 60 km to 68 km, the output for `vmean` should be:

`[-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5]`

For altitude 69 we should have a `NaN`. Then `altmean = [70 71]` should have `vmean = [-2 -1]`, corresponding to the values of `vtest1`. The averaging would begin whenever there's an overlap as in the range between 72 and 74 km, which should output:

`altmean = [72 73 74]`
`vmean = [-1.5 -0.5 0.5]`

And the final output should be:

`altmean = [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]`
`vmean = [-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5 NaN -2 -1 -1.5 -0.5 0.5 0  1  2  3  4]`

The solution should be scaled up to 50 profiles.

Thanks a lot y'all

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is as follows (u's are just arrays with a different component of the winds):

```
def averagingarrays(alt1,v1,u1,alt2,v2,u2):

    altmin = np.min([np.min(alt1),np.min(alt2)])
    altmax = np.max([np.max(alt1),np.max(alt2)])

    altarray = np.arange(altmin,altmax+1,1)
    vmean = np.zeros(np.size(altarray))
    umean = np.zeros(np.size(altarray))
    vc = 0
    for alt in altarray:
        altw1 = np.where(alt1 == alt)[0]
        altw2 = np.where(alt2 == alt)[0]

        if np.size(altw1) != 0 and np.size(altw2) != 0:
            vmean[vc] = np.nanmean([v1[altw1], v2[altw2]])
            umean[vc] = np.nanmean([u1[altw1], u2[altw2]])
        if np.size(altw1) != 0 and np.size(altw2) == 0:
            vmean[vc] = v1[altw1]
            umean[vc] = u1[altw1]
        if np.size(altw2) != 0 and np.size(altw1) == 0:
            vmean[vc] = v2[altw2]
            umean[vc] = u2[altw2]
        if np.size(altw1) == 0 and np.size(altw2) == 0:
            vmean[vc] = np.NaN
            umean[vc] = np.NaN
            #print altw1, alt
        vc = vc+1

    return altarray,vmean,umean

aux = averagingarrays(testalt1,vtest1,utest1, testalt2,vtest2,utest2)

print averagingarrays(aux[0],aux[1],aux[2], testalt3,vtest3,utest3)
```